# Detecting characters on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

Let say in the text input field, I am typing a sentence. Then I input a certain character, for example, "@" like below:

```
I am writing this example with @ symbol.
```

Using the `keypress`, when the symbol is used, I want to check the character before and after it.

In this case, it will give two empty spaces.

Another example is:

```
This is another example using @text.
```

Here it should give a space as "before" and "t" for "after" the symbol.

How would I detect these characters when keypress condition is met?

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: What have your tried till now?

Comment: I tried `innerHTML` then indexing `@` when the symbol is pressed. But with multiple symbols, it was bit limited and got too complicated (I should clarify that I am using `contenteditable`)

Comment: Do you want the logic to be run immediately after an `@` is typed, or at a later time, e.g. on a click of a button?

Comment: I would like it to run immediately. Thanks! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) in conjunction with the `selectionStart` property on your input element, which allows you to get the position of the cursor.

```js
document.getElementById('example').addEventListener('input', function () {
    var text = this.value,
        cursor = this.selectionStart
    
    // the characters in question
    var previous = text.charAt(cursor - 2),
        current  = text.charAt(cursor - 1),
        next     = text.charAt(cursor)
    
    // do something cool
    console.log(previous, '|', current, '|', next)
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="example" value="edit this example text :)"/>
```